# Typescript Generic for cartesian product

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, cartesian-product

Here is a typescript Cartesian product iterator:

```js
export function* productIterator3<T1, T2, T3>(
  ...arr: [T1[], T2[], T3[]]
): Generator<[T1, T2, T3]> {
  const lengths = arr.map((component) => component.length);
  const total = lengths.reduce((prod, len) => prod * len, 1);
  console.log(lengths, total);
  for (let totalIndex = 0; totalIndex < total; totalIndex++) {
    const product = [];
    let reducedIndex = totalIndex;
    for (const iter of arr) {
      product.push(iter[reducedIndex % iter.length]);
      reducedIndex = Math.floor(reducedIndex / iter.length);
    }
    yield product as [T1, T2, T3];
  }
}

type Colors = 'blue' | 'red';
const colors: Colors[] = ['blue', 'red'];
type Sizes = 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
const sizes: Sizes[] = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];
type Fits = 'turtleneck' | 'tank';
const fits: Fits[] = ['turtleneck', 'tank'];

for (const [color, size, fit] of productIterator3(colors, sizes, fits)) {
  console.log(color, size, fit); // color, size, fit are properly typed
}
```

The code itself isn't specific to the length of `...arr`, but the typescript annotations are. How do I adapt this to be fully generic? This isn't the correct syntax of course, but hopefully it gets the point across:

```js
export function* productIterator<...T>(...arr: [...T[]]): Generator<[...T]> {
```

Answer (score 0):

The key challenge here is finding a way to go between, for instance:

```
type TupleOfScalars = [string, number, bool];
type TupleOfArrays = [string[], number[], bool[]];
```

We can use an index signature using "in" for a union type [like so](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures#using-a-limited-set-of-string-literals) and then index into our type with that K.

```
type ArraysOfTuple<TupleOfScalars extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = {
  [K in keyof TupleOfScalars]: K extends number ? TupleOfScalars[K][] : never;
};

type ScalarsOfTuple<TupleOfArrays extends ReadonlyArray<unknown[]>> = {
  [K in keyof TupleOfArrays]: K extends number ? TupleOfArrays[K][number] : never;
};

type test1 = ArraysOfTuple<[number, string, boolean]>; // [number[], string[], boolean[]]
type test2 = ScalarsOfTuple<[number[], string[], boolean[]]>; // [number, string, boolean]
```

To break this down:

If we have a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) we can use it as an index for our type.

```
type Indices = 1 | 2 | 3 | 'someString';
type ThreeTuple = { [K in Indices]: number }; // { 3: number; 1: number; 2: number; someString: number; }
```

We can use `K` within that index to further specify the type of that particular attribute. `[K in Indices]: K`, for instance, would make it so `obj[1]` has the type `1`.

`keyof number[]` includes 0, 1, 2, etc., but it also includes 'toReversed' and other array functions. So if we just do:

```
type ArraysOfTuple<TupleOfScalars extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = {
  [K in keyof TupleOfScalars]: TupleOfScalars[K][]
};
```

We'll have `[string, number] => [string[], number[]]` as desired, but it could mess with the other properties. The ternary operator selects only the numeric indices to modify. `never` in the `else` clause drops the item from the ternary. See [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

My final signature:

```
export function* productIterator<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown[]>>(
  ...arr: T
): Generator<{ [K in keyof T]: K extends number ? T[K][number] : T[K] }> {
```

If you didn't have the numeric key distinction, `T[K] extends (infer U)[]` (as seen in the other answer) is `T[K] extends any[]` but will capture the type `U` for use in the ternary.